# how to handle more than 20 digit number (Big integer)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, biginteger

My angular program, I need to pass the number which is more than 20 digit to the API request.

```
num: any;

this.num = 2019111122001424290521878689;
console.log(this.num); // It displays "2.0191111220014244e+27"
```

I tried to change string from number as below

```
console.log(this.num.toString()); // It displays "2.0191111220014244e+27"
```

My expectation is that I need to pass the original big integer into the API request. If I pass as below, it goes as "2.0191111220014244e+27".

BTW, I tried BigInt(this.num), which gives difference number.

Suggest me

Comment: can't you keep this data as a string, do you need to do any calculation with it ?

Comment: Actually, I got this data from some external API where I got only integer. But, I can convert into a string and can pass it string in our API request.

Comment: In your case, i think that would make more sens, let your API handle big numbers.

Comment: No, My API does support only string. So, I must to convert into string. I am not sure about mathjs npm.. Anyidea other than mathjs?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, big integer literals have the letter `n` as a suffix:

```
var bigNum = 2019111122001424290521878689n;
console.log(bigNum);
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Answer (score 1):

If you got a large number (> SAFE_INTEGER) from an API, in JSON format, and you want to get the exact value, as as string, you unfortunately can't use `JSON.parse()`, as it will use the `number` type and lose precision.

There are alternative JSON parsers out there like LosslessJSON that might solve your problem.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative parser for Google apps script for this? i have big numbers from a json api response and BigInt also modifies them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigInt.
BigInt is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 253 - 1, which is the largest number JavaScript can reliably represent with the Number primitive. BigInt can be used for arbitrarily large integers.

```
const theBiggestInt = 9007199254740991n;

const alsoHuge = BigInt(9007199254740991);
// ↪ 9007199254740991n

const hugeString = BigInt("9007199254740991");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n

const hugeHex = BigInt("0x1fffffffffffff");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n

const hugeBin = BigInt("0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
// ↪ 9007199254740991n
```

BigInt is similar to Number in some ways, but also differs in a few key matters — it cannot be used with methods in the built-in Math object and cannot be mixed with instances of Number in operations; they must be coerced to the same type. Be careful coercing values back and forth, however, as the precision of a BigInt may be lost when it is coerced to a Number.

Refer to
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the number you have there is not an integer. Javascript can only store integers up to the value given by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. In chrome, this number is 9007199254740991.

The number you have is actually a floating point number, and converting it between floating point and integer will loose some precision.

Comment: According to the docs, yes. But in reality, browsers try to convert floating point to integers if they can to improve the performance of the calculations.

[read here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/)